Is there a way to manually move Whatsapp videos between iPhones?
A week ago I moved to a new iPhone, moving all my Whatsapp chats and media to the new one using iCloud backup. Now, I forgot to backup videos, too, thinking they would move along with the phone's standard camera storage.
I know the easiest way would be to just create a new backup with all the videos on the old phone and restore it on the new one, but I think that would replace some very important messages I got this week that I don't want to lose.
Is there a way to recover videos from the old phone without losing anything, maybe directly accessing the iPhone's Whatsapp storage?
